# R: y-axis does not fill the plotting area?

Tags: r, plot

I have a small subplot just with the axes:

[image]

```
par(mar=c(0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 37))
plot(NULL, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0,0), ylim=ylim.axis_right, type="n", ann=FALSE)
axis(4, at=c(ylim.axis_right[1], ylim.axis_right[1]/2, 0, ylim.axis_right[2]/2, ylim.axis_right[2]), labels=FALSE, lwd=6, col="#000000")
box()
```

Where ylim.axis_right is a 2-vector of form: (-x,x).
My problem is that I have provided the same ylim for both the dummy plot and axes most outside markers and I expected the actual axis to be stretched to the limits of the box. Why is it not happening and how should I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default,  R will increase the size of the plot by 4%. You can suppress that with yaxs="I". This is explained on the help page `?par`.

> **xaxs**
>   The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the x-axis. Possible values are "r", "i", "e", "s", "d". The styles are generally
>   controlled by the range of data or xlim, if given.
>   Style "r" (regular) first extends the data range by 4 percent at each end and
>   then finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within the extended range.
>   Style "i" (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels
>   that fits within the original data range.
>
> **yaxs**
>   The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the y-axis. See xaxs above.

So you can get the effect that you want by specifying `yaxs="i"`

```
par(mar=c(0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 29))
ylim.axis_right = c(-1,1)
plot(NULL, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=ylim.axis_right, type="n", ann=FALSE, yaxs="i")
axis(4, at=c(ylim.axis_right[1], ylim.axis_right[1]/2, 0, ylim.axis_right[2]/2, 
    ylim.axis_right[2]), labels=FALSE, lwd=6, col="#000000")
box()
```

[image: Axes aligned]